# how to get image from PHImageFileURLKey

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

guys.

I am getting images URL from photos by using below code.

```
func getAllImagesURL() -> [URL]
    {
       var arr_URL = [URL]()
        for index in 0..<fetchResult.count
        {
            imgManager.requestImageData(for: fetchResult.object(at: index) as PHAsset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
                if let fileName = (info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? URL)
                {
                    //do sth with file name
                    arr_URL.append(fileName)
                }
            })
        }
        return arr_URL
    }
```

By using this URL key I want to get the image from photos.I have searched and found below code.But it still not working.

```
func getImage(assetUrl: URL) -> UIImage?  {
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetUrl], options: nil)

        guard let result = asset.firstObject else {
            return nil
        }
        var assetImage: UIImage?
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: result, targetSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: options) { image, info in
            assetImage = image
        }

        return assetImage
    }
```

It returns nil.So please help me.How to get the image by using URL key.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I think you should learn about completion handlers or callback , there are many questions about this on SO, check this link for starter: https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

In the `getImage(assetUrl: URL) -> UIImage?` method, you are using

```
    let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetUrl], options: nil)
```

here `assetUrl` is the url that should be taken from if you are using the AssetsLibrary. This library is deprecated from iOS 9.0 onwards. We have to use Photos library instead.

BTW, you are already getting all the images(data) in `getAllImageURLs()` method. Just convert that method to get all the images and process those images as required. You can use the below method to get all the images.

```
func getAllImages() -> [UIImage]?
{
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]

    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)

    var allImages = [UIImage]()

    for index in 0..<fetchResult.count
    {
        let asset = fetchResult.object(at: index) as PHAsset
        imgManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (uiimage, info) in
            allImages.append(uiimage!)
        })
    }

    return allImages
}
```

NOTE: tweak this method as per your requirements.

Comment: If images in the device are greater than 10,000 then memory issue is occurring or not or images load performance is good or not.Please tell me